# Reading .txt files using StreamReader

Tags: vb.net

I am having an issue, I have a program I'm working on and I have to be able to read multiple .txt files one after the other to update a string array called `words()`. The main problem is the first file I upload goes into the `files()`string array, when I run my drag and drop event the array is full and won't let me upload second. how do I reset the `files()`array after it has been uploaded successfully.

sample code:

```
Dim words(7) As String
Dim i As Integer = 0
 Public Sub frmMain_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles MyBase.DragDrop

    Dim word As String = ""
    Try
        Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)

        For Each path In files

            MsgBox(path)
            Dim sr As New StreamReader(path)

            Do Until sr.Peek = -1
                word = sr.ReadLine()

                words(i) = word

                frmDefaultkWh.lbDefaultkWh.Items.Add(cbAppliances.Items(i) + " = " + words(i))
                i = i + 1

            Loop


        Next
        GetPower()
    Catch ex As Exception

        'MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())

    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub frmMain_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles MyBase.DragEnter

    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then

        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _"full"_ and also what the _**exact**_ problem is. The array cannot be "full" because you re-declare it every time `MyBase.DragDrop` is raised. It is impossible.

Comment: when I drag a second file to update the `words()` string array, i get a System.IndexOutOfRangeException, then the array doesn't update. If its not the `file()` array. Then how can I erase the values from the `words()` array after the next file is uploaded?

Comment: It seems `words` shouldn't be an array, but rather a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) since you need a collection with dynamic size (you never know how many words you'll find). Call `yourList.Add(<item here>)` to add new item to the list and `yourList.Clear()` to remove all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because you are not resetting i, which means that eventually i increments out of the range of your words() array which is only size 7, which by the way will also throw an error if one of those files has more than 7 lines.

```
    For Each path In files
          i = 0 'reset counter

          MsgBox(path)
          Dim sr As New StreamReader(path)

          Do Until sr.Peek = -1
              word = sr.ReadLine()

              words(i) = word

              frmDefaultkWh.lbDefaultkWh.Items.Add(cbAppliances.Items(i) + " = " +     words(i))
              i = i + 1

          Loop

      Next
```

Comment: Thank you for the fix. I tried that but I think I had it in the wrong place.